# Django password change does not take effect

Tags: django, authentication

If I change user's password via `./manage.py shell` using `django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password`, and then check if it was successfull via `User.check_password` - everything looks OK, but if then I try to authentificate using `django.contrib.auth.authenticate` - it returns nothing, like the password is wrong. Any ideas, please?

Comment: do you actually save user object after setting password?

Comment: @mariodev i swear, I did that... but now it works o_O...